# SEPA Debit received after invoice due date

Tags: european-union, direct-debit

I (a one-person company) use services from another company that invoices me every month with a 15 day payment term.

They also charge me automatically via a SEPA direct debit mandate, but their charges always arrive after the invoice due date.

This means that their invoices always expire, putting me in violation of their TOS, and if you take them literally, risking service termination.

I already complained to their customer support team, but they don't see the problem, stating that I could just ignore the date.

#### Is there any regulation (EU/The Netherlands) that requires you to charge your customers within the payment term of an invoice when you are in control of the debit process?

Answer (score 1):

Are you afraid *they* are going to terminate the contract with *you* because *they* are too incompetent to set the correct date for the direct debit billing? When they didn't withdraw the money on time when they could have done so, then *they* are the party at fault for the contract being violated. Also, having a longer time for settling a debt is generally considered to be in favor of the debtor, not the creditor. So by withdrawing the funds later than earlier, they are doing *you* a favor.

That being said: Keep in mind that it can take several days for banks to execute SEPA direct debit transfers. So it is very well possible that they initiate the transfer *exactly* on the invoice due date, which means you see the money leaving your bank account a couple days after that.